# Scheduling Python Script - Linux

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am trying to run a couple of experiments which take anywhere between 4-6 hours.

I am running these experiments using python. Is there way for me to automate so that I can run the experiments one after the other?

I looked at the `at` function in python. that only allows me to schedule it at a particular time. However, I don't know at what time the experiment ends.

could you suggest a `function` that I can use for scheduling or even how to automate using a  shell script? or an example

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could do the easy approach and just batch them up in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

date
python stage1.py ; date
python stage2.py ; date
python stage3.py ; date
python stage4.py ; date
python stage5.py ; date
python stage6.py ; date
```

Then either schedule, or just run, the script itself. That seems to be the easiest solution.

The calls to `date` are simply there so you can see how long each stage took. They may or may not be necessary, or they can be replaced with a different timing solution.

Comment: I think it would run them concurrently.  Let me give it a shot

Comment: @mish, it shouldn't run them concurrently unless they backgrounded themselves (or you forced it with `&`). Default is to run and wait until exit.

Comment: Yep!. it does the way you said.